# gulp-cssmin: How to change relative URLs in minified CSS

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I'm new to gulp and need your help with the **gulp-cssmin** plugin to minify my CSS files. 
My simple project structure:

```
gulpfile.js
  css/
    myCss.css
    min/
      myCss.min.css
  images/
    myImg.jpg
```

My goal is now to minify the CSS file `myCSS.css` in folder `css/`, rename it to `myCSS.min.css` and copy it to folder `css/min/`.
This is working as expected.
Now I'm using relative URL paths in my CSS file:

```
background-image: url("../images/myImg.jpg");
```

When copying the file to folder `css/min/`, the path is no longer correct. I need to rebase the URL.
How do I do this? I've tried to set the `target` option, with no effect.
My gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('css/*.css')
        .pipe(cssmin({ showLog: true, target: '../', keepBreaks: true }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/min'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two [options](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-api):

- `relativeTo`: the folder where your input files are located (i.e. `css/`)
- `target`: the folder that your output files are written to (i.e. `css/min/`)

So you end up with:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.src('css/*.css')
   .pipe(cssmin({ 
      showLog: true, 
      relativeTo: 'css/',
      target: 'css/min/', 
      keepBreaks: true
    }))
   .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('css/min'));
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: wont work if your files are in different sources, had to use https://github.com/joscha/gulp-rewrite-css